# google apps script send email with outlook

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, microsoft-graph-api

"https://github.com/tanaikech/OnedriveApp#utilities" I create an "Access token" by accessing Microsoft Azure with the tool in this link. But when sending mail with Google Apps Script I get the following error.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKHgR.png)

My Code

```
function sendmail()
{
  const obj = [
    {
      to: [{ name: "### name ###", email: "### email address ###" }, , ,],
      subject: "sample subject 1",
      body: "sample text body",
      cc: [{ name: "name1", email: "emailaddress1" }, , ,],
    },
    {
      to: [{ name: "### name ###", email: "### email address ###" }, , ,],
      subject: "sample subject 2",
      htmlBody: "<u><b>sample html body</b></u>",
      bcc: [{ name: "name1", email: "emailaddress1" }, , ,],
    },
  ];

  const prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const odapp = OnedriveApp.init(prop);
  const res = odapp.sendEmails(obj);
  console.log(res);
}
```

I am getting error running the script and wondering how to solve it.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. I confirmed the same issue now. I'm worried that the specification might be changed. So, I updated the library of [OnedriveApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/OnedriveApp). Please test it again. When I tested the updated library, I confirmed that the emails could be correctly sent. I apologize for this again.

Comment: I upgraded the library version to 10 and tried again. Unfortunately the same problem persists. (I'm using V8) I can view mail and create onedrive folder. But I still can't send mail.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I updated it to v1.2.1. And, when I tested the updated library, no error occurs, and emails can be correctly sent. I apologize for this situation. But, I would like to support you. So, when I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of a solution. By the way, how about removing the library and installing it again?

Comment: Unfortunately, when I delete the library and try again, it still gives the same error. I tried forwarding mail. It successfully forwards the mail. But I can't create and send new mail. It gives "Body" error.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I tested your showing script using my email address, no error occurs. I can confirm that your 2 emails can be correctly sent and also I can get them in my email. And, the returned value of `[{"id":"1","status":202,"headers":{"Cache-Control":"private"},"body":null},{"id":"2","status":202,"headers":{"Cache-Control":"private"},"body":null}]` is shown in the log. I apologize for this situation. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is how I solved the problem.
`to: [{ name: "### name ###", email: "### email address ###" }, , ,],`
After correcting this code as below, I was able to send mail successfully.
`to: [{ name: "### name ###", email: "### email address ###" }],`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I used `, , ,` of `[{ name: "### name ###", email: "### email address ###" }, , ,]` for showing that multiple elements can be used. I couldn't notice that you directly used it. I deeply apologize for this. But, I think that even when you used your modification, I'm worried that an error occurs using the older version because the specification of the request body has been changed. And, I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: It works on both the old library version (ver 9) and the new library version (ver 10)

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `It works on both the old library version (ver 9) and the new library version (ver 10)`, unfortunately, I confirmed an error at v1.2.0. I apologize for this. But, now, I updated it to v1.2.2. In this case, you can use `to: [{ name: "### name ###", email: "### email address ###" }, , ,]`. By this, your question was resolved by updating the library. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience.